# Writing a function to define class properties

Tags: python

I was recently writing a definition for a pretty basic data class in Python and I came up with the following:

```
class A:

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__a1 = kwargs.get('some_value', -1)

    @property
    def a1(self):
        return self.__a1

    @a1.setter
    def a1(self, new_a1):
        self.__a1 = new_a1
```

And it goes on. In this case, the value `-1` could be replaced with a variety of "null" values: `-1`, `""`, `[]`, etc., and `some_value` comes from an `Enum` I defined earlier.

Because the class definition contains several of these property definitions, and they're all very "same-y", I'd like to write a function to do this for me. I'm pretty sure it's possible in Python but I've never tried it so I was hoping for some pointers.

Comment: 1. Your current syntax is wrong. 2. Which part are you trying to simplify, `__init__` or the `@property`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe What's wrong with it? And I'm trying to simplify '__init__'

Comment: Just for the record: using "private" attributes and a dumb getter/setter pair over it is not pythonic - the point is: you just don't need it, as you can as well start with a plain public attribute, and turn it to a computed one later if and when needed. TL;DR : if all your property is doing is what a direct attribute access would do, dont use a property.

Comment: To add to bruno's comment: changing from direct access to `a1` to using a property named `a1` to interface with `__a1` is transparent to the user. Code like `x = a.a1` and `a.a1 = 3` will continue to work if you replace `a1` with a property of the same name that wraps access to `__a1`. In other words, don't worry about getters and setters until the need for them arises, because the conversion process is backwards-compatible with using bare attributes.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: I wasn't actually trying to do that when I wrote this. I don't particularly care about privacy for these classes as they're meant to be public. Rather, I was trying to use this as a foundation for more complex operations that might need to be added later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to simplify the repetitive property definitions, you can use a generic [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html) to simplify this significantly:

```
class ProtectedAttribute(object):
    """Basic descriptor functionality for a protected attribute.

    Args:
      name (str): The name of the attribute to back the descriptor
        (usually the name the descriptor is assigned to with a single
        additional leading underscore).

    """

    def __init__(self, name, **kwargs):
        self.name = name

    def __get__(self, obj, typ):
        return getattr(obj, self.name)

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        setattr(obj, self.name, value)

    def __delete__(self, obj):
        delattr(obj, self.name)
```

Now you can just do:

```
class A(object):

    a1 = ProtectedAttribute('__a1')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.a1 = kwargs.get("some_value", -1)
```

Note also the use of [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) to simplify `__init__`.

Comment: Oops yes pardon me! I dunno what I was thinking! Sorry!

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks, that looks good. Sorry to be a bother but could you point me to a tutorial on this sort of thing as well? I'd like to learn more

Comment: @user3121975 See: [Data Descriptors HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html)

Comment: Note that Bruno [makes a good point above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30889861/writing-a-function-to-define-class-properties/30890024#comment49821132_30889861) - I only use this class as a base for more complex descriptors, you might as well just use an unprotected attribute in this case.