Suppressing recommendations on AttributeError - Python 3.12
I like to use __getattr__ to give objects optional properties while avoiding issues with None. This is a simple example:
from typing import Any

class CelestialBody:

    def __init__(self, name: str, mass: float | None = None) -> None:

        self.name = name
        self._mass = mass

        return None

    def __getattr__(self, name: str) -> Any:

        if f"_{name}" not in self.__dict__:
            raise AttributeError(f"Attribute {name} not found")

        out = getattr(self, f"_{name}")
        if out is None:
            raise AttributeError(f"Attribute {name} not set for {self.name}")
        return out

My problem is that Python tries to be nice when I raise my custom AttributeError and exposes the "private" attribute for which I am creating the interface:
AttributeError: Attribute mass not set for Earth. Did you mean: '_mass'?

Is there a standard way to suppress these recommendations?

Don't those only appear in interactive mode? So how much does it matter, really?

Wouldn't your usecase be better handled by @property decorators instead of patching on the fly with __getattr__?

@matszwecja with a descriptor Python would still look for similar names in __dict__ on an AttributeError, so the code would be neater but wouldn't solve the OP's problem.

@matszwecja property works for this small example, but my real object has a list of some 8 private attributes, so the code quickly becomes redundant and difficult to maintain

@deceze apparently not, I don't use interactive mode at all

Writing it out longhand with @property, @x.setter etc. would be cumbersome, but if you write a custom descriptor, like https://stackoverflow.com/a/30890024/3001761, with your extra __get__ logic it wouldn't.

Interestingly there is some logic that looks like it's trying to suppress private suggestions.

@jonrsharpe I don't really want users to be able to change the mass of the Sun, but I like the idea of a custom descriptor for a more general case

I was able to suppress the suggestion by subclassing AttributeError in python 3.12.1

The name recommendation logic is triggered only if the name attribute of the AttributeError is not None:
elif exc_type and issubclass(exc_type, (NameError, AttributeError)) and \
        getattr(exc_value, "name", None) is not None:
    wrong_name = getattr(exc_value, "name", None)
    suggestion = _compute_suggestion_error(exc_value, exc_traceback, wrong_name)
    if suggestion:
        self._str += f". Did you mean: '{suggestion}'?"

So you can easily disable the suggestion by setting name to None when instantiating an AttributeError:
if out is None:
    raise AttributeError(f"Attribute {name} not set for {self.name}", name=None)

Demo here

This is a known issue: python/cpython#116871. It will be fixed in Python 3.13* via python/cpython#116930, which adds a feature to hide_underscored to the handling of AttributeError suggestions:
    if isinstance(exc_value, AttributeError):
        obj = exc_value.obj
        try:
            d = dir(obj)
            hide_underscored = (wrong_name[:1] != '_')
            if hide_underscored and tb is not None:
                while tb.tb_next is not None:
                    tb = tb.tb_next
                frame = tb.tb_frame
                if 'self' in frame.f_locals and frame.f_locals['self'] is obj:
                    hide_underscored = False
            if hide_underscored:
                d = [x for x in d if x[:1] != '_']
        except Exception:
            return None

So if the "wrong name" you tried to find ("mass") doesn't itself start with an underscore and you're not accessing the attribute on self, any names that do start with one will be excluded from the traceback suggestion. As far as I'm aware there's no option to disable these entirely in the meantime.

* this commit is tagged 3.13.0b1, although this feature's description hasn't (yet?) been added to What’s New In Python 3.13.
